# How to receive the same udp-stream in several programs?

Tags: windows, networking, udp, mpeg2-ts

I have a closed third party system that sends a unicast UDP stream (MPEG-TS) that I'd like to access in two different programs on the same computer. I can not change anything on the source, not even IP or Port.

Is there any other option than to write my own little program that captures the stream and then creates to new streams and resends both?

It seems that only one of the two destination programs handles multicast, so I need two unicast streams.

Comment: Can you re-configure the source to send to a multicast address instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to forward unicast UDP to a multicast group, or just save data into a file and process later.

#### Edit 0:

Here is an example (this is on Linux - don't have any Windows boxes). Listen on unicast port `4242`, forward to multicast `224.10.10.10:5252` (you might have to add `ip-multicast-loop` option if you are doing everything on the same machine):

```
~$ socat UDP-LISTEN:4242 UDP-DATAGRAM:224.10.10.10:5252
```

Receive on multicast (needs interface address or name), forwards to unicast `192.168.0.1:6666`:

```
~$ socat UDP-RECVFROM:5252,ip-add-membership=224.10.10.10:eth0,reuseaddr,fork \
   UDP-DATAGRAM:192.168.0.1:6666
```

Run two of the above with different destination addresses (`reuseaddr` option allows these to be run on the same machine).

Comment: Updated the question to reflect that I need two unicast streams.

Comment: You can daisy-chain `socat` then: unicast->multicast->unicast times 2.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use socat - could you write up an example? unicast->multicast and then multicast->unicast again. Data only needs to flow in one direction.

Comment: When I try to run your first example (uni->multi) I get an error message: _socat[5216.2147582376] E address "UDP-LISTEN..." in endpoint context, leftdirs=4, with 1 parameter(s) is not available_ - any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I don't have any Windows boxes here to test on. Try other options like `UDP4-LISTEN`, `UDP-RECVFROM`, `UDP4-RECVFROM`.

Comment: Using UDP4-Listen worked - I guess it was trying using IPv6... Thanks a lot for the help!